# Run Docker CMD in context of a Sub Directory of WORKDIR

Tags: node.js, docker

I need the CMD to run in context of a package.json file that lives in `/app/server`. Right now it's running yarn in **app** `root` where there is no package.json:

```
FROM node:14.8.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
ENV PORT 8080
COPY app ./
CMD [ "yarn", "start-server" ]
```

Comment: WORKDIR is set to /app so that's where you end up when you start.  You might want to add another `WORKDIR /app/server` in front of your CMD ? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this 2 ways:

1. The correct way is to use an extra `WORKDIR`:

   ```
   FROM node:14.8.0-alpine`
   WORKDIR /app
   ENV PORT 8080
   COPY app ./
   WORKDIR /app/server
   CMD [ "npm", "run", "serve" ]
   ```
2. You can specify a shell command as the image's `CMD` including a `cd` to change directories at startup:

   ```
   CMD cd /server && npm run serve
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WORKDIR` multiple times.

```
FROM node:14.8.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
ENV PORT 8080
COPY app ./
WORKDIR /app/server
CMD [ "yarn", "start-server" ]
WORKDIR /app
```